# alfresco repository tomcat username for solr when use third-party cert?

Tags: tomcat, solr, alfresco

I m getting `HTTP Status 401 - Cannot authenticate with the provided credentials` when alfresco trying to use solr search.

I got a free class1 key from startSSL. and [alfresco wiki](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_And_SOLR#Generating_new_SSL_certificates) says the `REPO_CERT_DNAME` must match tomcat username for `roles=repository`

but since I didn't generated the keypair by myself like the wiki said. how do I know what should I put for tomcat username?

the issuer?

the subject?

the friendly name?  the friendly name has    some random number on it like

```
1.2.840.xxxxx.3.9.1=#16117765626d61737465724xxxxxxxxxxxx,CN=Domain.com,C=US,2.5.4.13=#1310446c5a344a4dxxxxxxxxx4453834
```

note: I already solve `unable to find valid certification path to requested target` error, so I think it may not related to keystore stuffs

Comment: Did you check your tomcat access logs? That normally shows you the name from the certificate for cert based auth

Comment: I just checked, using patthern = "combined" no user is showing:    .xx.94.75.xxx - - [26/Oct/2012:08:48:42 -0500] "GET /solr/ HTTP/1.1" 401 1101 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2012:08:48:45 -0500] "POST /alfresco/service/api/solr/modelsdiff HTTP/1.1" 401 1101 "-" "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"